# How to include full URL in PHP within echo HTML content

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to load content to an HTML page using PHP files.  I've done this successfully using the `echo` statement.  The issue I am running into now is using full URL's that sit within the HTML within the `echo` statement - whenever the PHP file sees two backslashes `//` it starts to comment out the code for that line, then seems to ignore the rest of the HTML as part of the `echo`

How can I use this PHP file to successfully load HTML content that contains URLs?  See below for a code reference.

```
<?php

echo "
<div class="footer">


<!--   *****   Social media icons   *****   -->
<div class="socialIcons">

    <ul>
        <li><a href="http://www.twitter.com/" title="Twitter"><img src="./design/twitter.jpg" alt="My Twitter" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.pinterest.com/" title="Pinterest"><img src="./design/pinterest.jpg" alt="My Pinterest" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.linkedin.com/" title="LinkedIn"><img src="./design/linkedin.jpg" alt="Me on LinkedIn" /></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<ul>
<li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Contact</a></li>
<li><a href="javascript:void(0)">About</a></li>
<li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Privacy</a></li>
</ul>

</div>
"
?>
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/de/function.include.php

Comment: That's because you are using `"` to start the `echo` and then using `"` again to assign the parameters to the elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Comment:** That's because you are using `"` to start the echo and then using `"` again to assign the parameters to the elements.*

```
<?php

echo '
    <div class="footer">

        <!--   *****   Social media icons   *****   -->
        <div class="socialIcons">

            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="http://www.twitter.com/" title="Twitter">
                        <img src="./design/twitter.jpg" alt="My Twitter" />
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="http://www.pinterest.com/" title="Pinterest">
                        <img src="./design/pinterest.jpg" alt="My Pinterest" />
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="http://www.linkedin.com/" title="LinkedIn">
                        <img src="./design/linkedin.jpg" alt="Me on LinkedIn" />
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="javascript:void(0)">Contact</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="javascript:void(0)">About</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="javascript:void(0)">Privacy</a>
            </li>
        </ul>

    </div>
';
?>
```

Change the `echo` initial and final `"` to `'`. Problem solved.

Comment: Excellent!  That fixed it, thank you.  I had to also add an HTML character reference for an apostrophe that existed in my actual code (&#39;) but otherwise my problem is solved.

Comment: You could escape the apostrophe by doing `\'` ;)

Comment: Thanks.  This is why we have stackoverflow.  :)

Answer (score 2):

you use the wrong "" charakters. at the beginning you user "" all in "" have to be this ' '.

Comment: First edition was crystal clear :)